# jUnit change behavior of a method

Tags: java, junit, mocking, powermock

I have to make some jUnit tests for some methods and I can't change the source code. Is there any possibility to change the behavior of a function without change source code?
Look a straight-forward example: Class A and B are source code (can't change them). I want to change behavior of run() method from A when I call it in B through testing() in Junit test. Any ideas?

```
public class A {
    public String run(){
        return "test";
    } 
}

public class B {
    public void testing() {
        String fromA = new A().run(); //I want a mocked result here
        System.out.println(fromA);
    }
}

public class C {
    @Test
    public void jUnitTest() {
        new B().testing();
        // And here i want to call testing method from B but with a "mock return" from run()         
    }
}
```

Comment: unit tests are to test your methods, not to alter what they (are supposed to) do. You can mock them, though. Look up Mockito. It's a tool to help you mock results.

Comment: How would you use mock in this case? Without mocking testing method?

Comment: use javaassist to change behavior of class or methods, It is byte-code manipulation library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) and [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/):

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(B.class)
public class C {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        A a = spy(new A());
        when(a.run()).thenReturn("mock return");
        PowerMockito.whenNew(A.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(a);
    }

    @Test
    public void jUnitTest() {
        new B().testing();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't test that the way you want and not change source code. You can't mock local variables. I would suggest to you add new method to `B.class` which will return `new A()` and `spy` it using [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html).

```
@Test
public void test(){
    final B spy = Mockito.spy(new B());    
    Mockito.doReturn(new C()).when(spy).getA();
} 

class C extends A {
    @Override
    public String run(){return "new String";}
}
```

Use byte-code libraries in tests not a good idea.